# Why doesn't my oracle asm disks show up under dbca?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-asm

I am running into a problem where I have created some ASM disks under linux, they show up when I run oracleasm listdisks, but they are invisible when I use dbca and try to Configure Automatic Storage Management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a a missing rpm package. Next time I'll be a little more careful to verify that rpm does install everything I ask it to install.

Answer (score -1):

pardon my ignorance, but why would you want to use ASMLib anyway? you can
use raw devices, be it block or character, even without the ASMLib. ASMLib requires
kernel drivers and that is something that I don't like. Kernel drivers must be compiled
for the kernel, they taint kernel and can potentially cause problem with Red Hat support.
Why not use disk partitions directly?